# interoperability

Tags: interop, definition

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what "interoperability" and "interoperability concerns" mean in terms of Software Engineering. Can someone please give me an example of what an interoperability concern is may be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Interoperability generally refers to the ability of multiple independent modules communicating via a common protocol. Maybe you want to edit the question to be a little more specific?

Comment: oh sorry about that em im not sure how to be more specific. For example when one system (e.g. a standalone general practice medical system) has to be incorporated into a larger system. What would the interoperability concerns be?

Comment: how about yo start doing your homework by reading the references list given !!

Answer (score 4):

Interoperability means intercommunication of code written in different programming languages. For example, when you call a WINAPI function (which is in C) from your C# code you are using interop.

Interop concerns are therefore concerns about interoperability. For example, when writing a C++ dll, you might want to keep your interface types POD's to enable later interoperability with C and .NET

Answer (score 0):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability#Software):

> According to ISO/IEC 2382-01,
>   Information Technology Vocabulary,
>   Fundamental Terms, interoperability is
>   defined as follows: "The capability to
>   communicate, execute programs, or
>   transfer data among various functional
>   units in a manner that requires the
>   user to have little or no knowledge of
>   the unique characteristics of those
>   units".

**Example**: The interoperability of .doc documents between different word processors.

Answer (score 0):

See [interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability) in Wikipedia

> the ability of two or more systems or components to exchange information and to use the information that has been exchanged.